# Odoo 13 error in xml file while adding fields in custom module

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-13

```
I am getting this error while upgrading my custom module in odoo13 while upgrading it , the error is within this xml file.i have added somoe fields in xml file then it showing me this erro
```

error :

Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 392, in _check_xml
    self.postprocess_and_fields(view.model, view_doc, view.id)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 964, in postprocess_and_fields
    self.raise_view_error(message, view_id)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 592, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Field `state` does not exist

Error context:
View `view.demo.form`
[view_id: 1710, xml_id: gunalan_demo.request_form, model: car.request, parent_id: n/a]

```
models.py:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api , _



class gunalan_demo(models.Model):
     _name = 'car.request' #Tables in DB =>car_request
     _description = 'demo module'

     name = fields.Char(string="Request_demo",required = True ,)
     date_from = fields.Datetime(string='starting date',default=fields.Datetime.now(),)
     date_to = fields.Datetime(string='Ending date',required=False,)

     emplyoee_id= fields.Many2one(comodel_name="hr.employee", string="Emplyoee ", required=True,)
     car_id =  fields.Many2one(comodel_name="fleet.vehicle", string="Car ", required=True,)

     state = fields.Selection(string="Status", selection=[('draft', 'Draft'), ('confirm', 'Confirm'),('validate','Validate'),('refuse','Refuse')('approved','Approved'),], default="draft", )
views.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>

    <record id ="request_form" model ="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">view.demo.form</field>
      <field name="model">car.request</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string ="Car Request Form">

          <header>
            <!--<button name="" string="" class="oe_highlight" states="" type=""/>-->
            <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,confirm,validate,refuse,approved"/>
          </header>

          <sheet>
            <div class="oe_title">
              <label for="name" class="oe_title_only"/>
              <h1>
                <field name="name" placeholder="Request Demo"/>
                </h1>
            </div>  
            <group>
              <group>
                  <field name="date_from"/>
                  <field name="date_to"/>
              </group>
              <group>
                <field name="emplyoee_id"/>
                <field name="car_id"/>

              </group>  
            </group>


          </sheet>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>

    <record id='request_tree' model='ir.ui.view' >
        <field name='name'>view.demo.tree</field>
        <field name='model'>car.request</field>
        <field name='arch' type='xml'>
            <tree string='Car Request Tree'>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="emplyoee_id"/>
                <field name="car_id"/>
                <field name="date_from"/>
                <field name="date_to"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_request_views" model="ir.actions.act_window">
      <field name="name">Car Request</field>
      <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
      <field name="res_model">car.request</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
      <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
          Car Request
        </p><p>
          Click here to add
        </p>
      </field>
    </record>

    <!-- This Menu Item will appear in the Upper bar, That's why It needs NO parent or action -->
    <menuitem id="menu_car_request_root" name="Car Request" sequence="10"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_car_request_categ" name="Car Request" parent="menu_car_request_root" sequence="1"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_car_request" name="Car Request" parent="menu_car_request_categ" action="action_request_views" sequence="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added your model.py file in init.py file. If you have added model.py inside model folder, then make sure model is given in init.py file.